# Websphere application server start access denied

Tags: websphere, access-denied, application-server

After the installation of websphere in my machine(Windows 7), I created a new websphere application server. gave the classpath and everything. Now when I am trying to start the server  there is an error coming: server could not be started. View JVM logs for further details.

In the logs it was mentioned : Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission com.ibm.ws.dist.trace.format.on.zos read)

Comment: Are you running server from deployment manager or by using command? If you are starting it by command the check that the user which is starting the server have the necessary permission to start it. For testing try starting it as an administrator( or root).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the start server and select "Run as administrator"...see if that help.